# Which ZMQ pattern should I use for this scenario?

Tags: multithreading, zeromq, pyzmq

I am new to ZMQ and multithreading design, so I hope to get some insights into the design pattern for my scenario:

I have a server that works as a middleware, which will receive external data from the database at a fixed rate, then it will forward the data to its connected clients. The server will do some filter so that each client will only receive a part of the data; sometimes clients will also send back responses after receiving data and the server needs to handle and store the responses into the database.

Since there may be hundreds of clients connected to the server per second, I am thinking of using the Router-Dealer pattern for the server-client part; As for the server-database part, probably using one of the worker thread for receiving the external data and forwarding it to other workers inside server through "inproc" protocol would be a good idea？

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to answer without knowing all the details, but here are some pointers that might get you in the right direction.

Instead of using threads,  you can consider use multiplexing using `zmq_poll()`. I guess this is `zmq.Poller` in PyZMQ. This is often much simpler to set up than threads. It is a good choice if the middleware does not have to do much work for each message. You can also combine the two approaches: a limited set of threads where each thread handles multiple connections using multiplexing.

Router-Dealer is a good choice if the traffic is not strictly Request-Response. You can also consider using multiple socket connections between client and server, for example:

- A Push-Pull connection for updates from the middleware to the client.
- A Push-Pull connection for responses from the client to the middleware.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. After reading ZMQ guide for a while, I found that using the ROUTER pattern along with ZMQ poller solved my question. Thank you so much for your advice!